# Broken Apache configuration after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-yosemite

Yesterday I upgraded to Yosemite and now my local configuration for web development is not working anymore.

I managed to set up a userdir under `/Users/user/public_html` and I could access all the websites via `localhost/~user/websitename`. Nothing special, but it took me a while to configure.

Looking in the apache directory I saw that many files were replaced, keeping a backup. I tried putting back the files with my settings again, but still is not working. Maybe I'm missing some file that I don't remember.

This is httpd-userdir.conf:

```
# Settings for user home directories
#
# Required module: mod_userdir

#
# UserDir: The name of the directory that is appended onto a user's home
# directory if a ~user request is received.  Note that you must also set
# the default access control for these directories, as in the example below.
#
UserDir public_html

#
# Users might not be in /Users/*/Sites, so use user-specific config files.
#
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
<IfModule bonjour_module>
       RegisterUserSite customized-users
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Users/*/public_html/">
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then in http.conf I have enabled some modules:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
```

and this:

DocumentRoot "/Users/user/public_html"

```
Directory "/Users/user/public_html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

If I simply try to access `localhost`, it displays the message "It works!". If I go to `localhost/user` simply doesn't load and the same if I try to access one of the websites.

Did I miss any file? In the apache logs it doesn't even display any error.

Comment: Yosemite upgrades Apache from 2.2 to 2.4.  The configuration has changed.  Did you enable the mod_userdir module?  Also you'll want to change your "Order" and "Allow" directives.  You may want to review the upgrade guidelines http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Future readers may want to start with [installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X Yosemite](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/) the *right way*.

Comment: Also, read this [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602475#26885389](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602475#26885389)

Answer (score 18):

OS X 10.10 Yosemite comes with Apache 2.4 instead of Apache 2.2 in Mavericks.
The major difference in configuration is that you have to replace...

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

...with...

```
Require all granted
```

See Apache doc's manual [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) for more details.

**UPDATE:**
Please be aware that after upgrading OS X you will usually find your old config files as backups next to the new ones written by Yosemite. They are labeled e.g. *httpd.conf.pre-update* and/or *httpd.conf~previous* and can be found in the same paths as the new configs (e.g. in */private/etc/apache2*).

Comment: Uncommenting the two lines referring to userdir in httpd.conf, uncommenting the Include in httpd-userdir.conf and making the above change in Guest.conf finally fixed the ~Guest site for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael if you do a clean install of Apache 2.4 you won't find any Order or Allow lines. But if you take over an existing configuration from Apache 2.2 you should definitely find them in httpd.conf (e.g. following the DocumentRoot directive line) as well as in httpd-vhosts.conf (if you use virtual hosts).

Comment: @Jpsy I understand that, what I'm saying is I have grepped all my config files (which were 2.2 but now are some mix of 2.2 and 2.4 due to the Yosemite upgrade) and I don't see those strings in either one.  Also I just went to double-check this and apparently Yosemite also broke my sshd setup, so I can't currently log in remotely.

Comment: @Michael are you aware that Yosemite not simply rewrites your config files but also keeps the old versions as backups? They are labeled e.g. *httpd.conf.pre-update* and/or *httpd.conf~previous* and can be found in the same paths as the new configs (e.g. */private/etc/apache2*). I have added this information to my answer.

Comment: @Jpsy thanks, yes I was aware of that.  the problem in my case is that it seems to be a bit more complicated than simply changing Order/Allow to Require (per the link you sent me).

Answer (score 1):

After attempting to fix this problem for 6 hours I was finally able to get this to work. I edited the httpd.conf, httpd-userdir.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf, etc to no avail. Leaving all of these files unedited from the yosemite configuration, what finally worked for me was to edit the httpd_server_app.conf located at `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/` by adding the following (for each site) as follows:

```html
<Directory />
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/">
 Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/[OTHER SITE DIRECTORY]/">
 Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

***Make sure if you use textedit to edit this file you undo the automatic insertion of the slanted quotation marks otherwise you will get a unicode error message.***

Hope this helps!