# Apache no longer server SSL after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: apache, ssl, osx-yosemite

After upgrading to Yosemite I am no longer able to use my web server.   It was set up to accept SSL connections on port 443, but now `netstat -a -n` says it isn't even listening on that port.  I looked in `/etc/apache2` and noticed that `extra/` had been moved to `original/extra` so I moved that back.  There was also a copy of `httpd.conf` in `original/` but the timestamp and size was unchanged and diff showed it was identical to my original `httpd.conf`.  The only other file in `/etc/apache2` which has a new timestamp is `users/` but nothing in that directory is changed.

All my certificate files in `ssl/` still have the correct permissions.  I don't see anything in `/var/log/apache2/error_log` (aside from the normal startup messages).  In fact, even if I try to access the web server on port 80 I get nothing in either `error_log` or `access_log` even though I unexpectedly get `403 Forbidden` on every page I try to access.

I have read about problems with Yosemite updating Apache from 2.2 to 2.4, but my web server doesn't even seem to be functional to the point of fixing any error caused by that.  In any case, I did try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484721/broken-apache-configuration-after-upgrading-to-yosemite), but my httpd.conf file does not contain any `Order` or `Allow` lines (nor does any file in `extra`/) so I can't try the answer suggested there.

Answer (score 7):

OK, this is an old topic, but here's an answer.

I believe you have to uncomment a few lines in httpd.conf.

Run:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Uncomment the following lines:

```
#LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so

#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

A simple trick is to search the configuration file using VIM to find lines related to SSL and debug from there.

In VIM, the following will find all instances of ssl... press n to go to next found instance:

```
?ssl
```

Once you made changes, test your configuration using:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

If all is good, run:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

If you get the following error:

SSLCertificateFile: file '/private/etc/apache2/server.crt' does not exist or is empty

Create a default self-signed SSL certificate:

```
cd /private/etc/apache2

openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key
```

Enter localhost when asked for your Common Name.

Then run configtest and, if all is good, restart.